# What happens when we allocate more executors to a spark job than numbers of partitions of a kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Suppose I am running spark batch job and I am setting 
--num-executors 40

1. The job reads a kafka topic with 20 partitions.
2. The job writes to a kafka topic with 20 partitions.

My question is :
How many executors will be used by the spark job 
a. While reading from kafka
b. While writing to kafka

What changes when I set below parameter while running the same job with 40 executors
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to answer the question directly spark will use **20 executors only**(as the input kafka partitions), remaining executors will be allocated any task.

Also the executors usage will be depends on the **transformations and actions** that you are going to perform with the data. For example

1. If you applied **foreach** function then , partition count will be same and executors will be the same.
2. If you applied **map and re partitioned** then based on the new partition executors will be invoked.

The Best practice is to maintain 2 to 3 times the partitions that the default partitions.

So once you have RDD , use the sparkcontext.defaultParalleism() to get default partitions after that re partition RDD to 2 to 3 times of it.
should be like this

newRDD= **RDD.repartition(2*sparkcontext.defaultParalleism());**

If spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false , then spark can't allocate the required executors based on the load.

***Always use spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true and re partition RDD to 2 to 3 times of default size.***

Comment: Thanks @Hari , What about while writing to Kafka topic ?

Comment: If you look at the best practice below example 


`dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    val producer = createKafkaProducer()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach { message =>
      connection.send(message)
    }
    producer.close()
  }
}`

Writing to kafka will be purely depends on the number of partitions that RDD has been splitted , if your RDD has 20 partitions , it will use all the 20 executors for writing to kafka. Please upvote , if your if answered.